# Python Unicode Conversion for latin characters

Tags: python

I am generating the Payload for API, which includes some string with Latin Characters

E.g.
I have a string 'Ul Świętojańska 12'.
I want to convert it to Unicode as 'Ul \u015awi\u0119toja\u0144ska 12'

I tried using encode() but it's not giving the required output.
Also, i used urllib.parse.quote(), but this conversion does not fit right in code.

In one of the reference code, i saw requests.utils.quote() is used. But this module not found in Python 3

Which module should be used and how?

Seeking some assistance.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give a try `raw_unicode_escape` or `unicode_escape` i.e.

```
text = "Ul Świętojańska 12"
print(text.encode("raw_unicode_escape"))
print(text.encode("unicode_escape"))
```

output

```
b'Ul \\u015awi\\u0119toja\\u0144ska 12'
b'Ul \\u015awi\\u0119toja\\u0144ska 12'
```

Read [`codecs` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings) for more information